# #1146 - Tabla 'database.paramname' no existe

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Estoy usando transacciones Sql en laravel para insertar una venta que modifica varias tablas (invoice, detail_invoice, kardex, products). No obstante hay veces en que toca hacer rollback en algunas tablas porque quizás haya algún fallo. cuando se hace Rollback he notado que sql no reinicia el auto_increment. Por ejemplo si se insertó un invoice cuyo id es 19 y se hace rollback porque quizas otra tabla tuvo un problema de inserción el invoice con id 19 es borrado. Sin embargo, si en la siguiente todo sale bien se vuelve a insertar un invoice con id 20. Osea del 18 pasa al 20 omitiendo el 19. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que en la excepcion una vez se haga el DB::rollback(); se ejecute un procedimiento almacenado que reinicie el id de todas las tablas y siga el consecutivo normal. No obstante estoy teniendo problemas con ese procedimiento. el se crea bien pero cuando lo llamo me sale un error como si tomara el parámetro de manera literal.

Mi procedimiento es este:

```
       DELIMITER $$
          CREATE PROCEDURE resetID(paramName varchar(20))
          BEGIN
           ALTER TABLE paramName AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
          END $$
```

Se crea bien. El detalle es que cuando lo llamo me sale este error.

```
CALL resetID('details');
#1146 - Tabla 'database.paramname' no existe
```

Pareciera que hay un problema al leer el string. Ese es mi problema

Comment: ¿Ese PA lo invocas desde Laravel?

Comment: BetaM aun no lo uso en laravel. Lo estoy probando primero en mysql a ver si funciona pero no está funcionando. Creo que si no funciona en mysql tampoco lo hará en laravel. De todos modos en Laravel lo haría así:  DB::select('call resetID(?)',array('details'));

Comment: Entiendo, solo te preguntaba para comprobar y confirmar mi edición quitando el tag de Laravel que al momento no tiene que ver aqui

Comment: Ese comportamiento, dejar huecos en los ids, te lo podrás encontrar por otras causas y no tiene más problemas que los "estéticos" que te puedan parecer. De todas formas usando Laravel quizá sería mejor subsanar esto en el propio diseño de la librería de acceso a base de datos. Los procedimientos almacenados facilitan procesos complejos y esto lo puedes hacer con una consulta sencilla.

Comment: Este tipo de operaciones se hacen con consultas preparadas. Algo así más o menos: **`DELIMITER $$ CREATE  PROCEDURE resetID (IN paramName VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
 SET @m_sql =CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',paramName, ' AUTO_INCREMENT=0');
 PREPARE stmt FROM @m_sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$`**

Comment: A. Cedano esa es la respuesta

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql). Supongo que lo correcto sería `DB::query('ALTER TABLE ? AUTO_INCREMENT=0',array('details'));`

Answer (score 2):

Los campos auto-incrementales de la base de datos tienen ese comportamiento y es normal. En otras palabras, **no debieras basarte en un campo auto-incremental para implementar un ID que no tenga agujeros**.

Con lo que estás haciendo estas restando capacidad de tu sistema de soportar de manera correcta usuarios concurrentes, en el peor de los casos, y no va a tener el efecto que esperas, en el mejor de ellos.

Imagina un escenario donde un usuario A inicia una transacción para insertar una factura que tiene 3 detalles.

En el mismo milisegundo, pero una fracción después, un usuario B inicia una transacción para insertar una factura que tiene más detalles.

Imaginemos un caso donde las transacciones van dándose cronológicamente de la siguiente manera:

---

| Usuario | Operación | ID Factura | ID Detalle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | **Inicia transacción** |  |  |
| A | Inserta encabezado de factura | 10 |  |
| B | **Inicia transacción** |  |  |
| A | Inserta detalle |  | 51 |
| B | Inserta encabezado de factura | 11 |  |
| B | Inserta detalle |  | 52 |
| A | Inserta detalle |  | 53 |
| B | Inserta detalle |  | 54 |
| A | Inserta detalle |  | 55 |
| B | Inserta detalle |  | 56 |
| B | Inserta detalle |  | 57 |
| A | Actualiza existencias y encuentra error por existencia insuficiente |  |  |
| A | **ROLLBACK** |  |  |
| B | Inserta detalle |  | 58 |
| B | Inserta detalle |  | 59 |
| B | Inserta detalle |  | 60 |
| B | Inserta detalle |  | 61 |
| B | Inserta detalle |  | 62 |
| B | Actualiza existencias, todo OK |  |  |
| A | **commit** |  |  |

Tus opciones si no quieres ver un agujero son:

- tendrías que gestionar de alguna manera para que B no pueda iniciar transacción hasta que termine A (con lo cual echas a la basura el gran trabajo que ha hecho la gente que diseña las bases de datos para soportar concurrencia),
- paras intentando rellenar los agujeros (cosa de locos, te puedo poner un ejemplo con 5 usuarios concurrentes)
- aceptar que los auto-incrementales de las bases de datos no son para llevar números de factura u otros consecutivos (¿números de cheque, de nómina?) que pertenecen al dominio del usuario. Los auto-incrementales de bases de datos están diseñados para el manejo de campos de uso interno del sistema, generalmente campos que se utilizan como llave primaria u otros que requieren soporte de concurrencia, lo cual conlleva que puedan tener agujeros en el correlativo.

Comment: cada que se crea un Id, ese mismo id lo obtengo y tengo por decirlo así un id_secindario donde concateno por ejemplo 'P000'. $idInsertado. Eso se ve mal?

Comment: Si, utiliza otro mecanismo para llevar el consecutivo de facturas, sobre todo si es un consecutivo _legal_. Los que existen a nivel de base de datos, como ya he explicado, son para otro caso de uso.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder pasar nombres de tabla o columnas de forma dinámica a una SP tienes que usar [consultas preparadas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html).

Por ejemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
    CREATE  PROCEDURE resetID (IN paramName VARCHAR(20)) 
    BEGIN  
        SET @m_sql =CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',paramName, ' AUTO_INCREMENT=0');  
        PREPARE stmt FROM @m_sql;  
        EXECUTE stmt;  
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
    END $$
```

Comment: eso segun la documentacion se llama server-side prepared statements. La verdad no sabía eso. Es algo nuevo de mysql cierto?

Comment: Es algo [relativamente nuevo](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/274).